# Где новичку искать хорошие задачки для практики[Java]

Tags: java

Не могу найти хорошую практику по Java, javarush не подходит. 
Прочитал книгу Head First Java. Нужны более менее производственные задачки, с алгоритмами и прочим...

Comment: Есть неплохой ресурс с простыми задачками codingbat.com

Comment: А по какой причине javarush не подходит?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

нигде.

- напиши gui-блокнот для заметок,
- напиши cli-версию
- переведи обе версии на локальную базу данных. на mysql/mongo/cassandra
- сделай многопользовательский блокнот для заметок. (на sqlite)
- отформатируй hdd/sdd  в виртуальной машине, явой. сделай это с компом своего друга и победи в драке.
- напиши апи для управления роботом в какой-нибудь игре.
- напиши игру.
- напиши бота, который будет посылать всех на три буквы на стаковерфлоу, но так нежно, чтобы его не банили
- господи, пойди уже и сделай что-нибудь полезное кроме изучения алгоритмов.
- сходи в гитхаб, посмотри на баги java-проектов, почини их
- устройся на работу, получи психотравму, справься с ней.

Comment: на кассандру даже с неплохим бэкграундом надо потратить добрых две-четыре недели на ознакомление с интерналсами